# VB Script If then End statement

Tags: if-statement, vbscript

I am trying to convert a macro to VB script and I am running into an issue at the 'if..then..end' statement . Here is my code.

```
Option Explicit

Public OpenedWB

Dim valueEntered, fileCount
Dim userResponse
Dim NewWB, NewWS
Dim i
Dim OpenedWBName
Dim Found
Dim FSO, txtFILE
Dim HostFolder
Dim dApproved, dPrepared, filearray()
Dim xlApp
Dim xlCalculationManual
Dim xlCalculationAutomatic, msoFileDialogFolderPicker, msoFileDialogViewSmallIcons

xlCalculationManual = -4135: xlCalculationAutomatic = -4105
msoFileDialogFolderPicker = 4: msoFileDialogViewSmallIcons = 7

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlApp.Visible = True

Set NewWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
NewWB.Windows(1).Visible = True
Set NewWS = NewWB.Worksheets.Add

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

With xlApp
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
End With

i = -1

'UI (Dynamic) Directory
With xlApp.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Title = "Select the folder to scan through sub-folders"
    .ButtonName = "Select this folder!"
    .InitialFileName = _
        "\\..somepath"
    .InitialView = msoFileDialogViewSmallIcons
    If .Show <> i Then End  'This is throwing an error (Expected statement error)
    HostFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
End With
```

I am not sure why I'm getting this error as it works fine in VBA, but I'm guessing it's because I have the code in a VBA subprocedure.

Can anyone help me out with this?

Thanks

Comment: VB, VBScript, VBA, they are similar but have differences. Maybe the `If` is expecting `End With` instead of `End`? Why not just change `If .Show <> i Then End` to `If .Show = i Then` instead and not deal with `End` at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is your intent? If you mean to use `End` as a statement that ends the program then you should know that **there is no `End` statement in VBScript**, it [only exists in "full-fat" VB6, VBA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/end-statement) [and VB.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/end-statement) where it's the "End program" command (but you shouldn't use it anyway because it doesn't perform any program clean-up and can result in leaking resources that need disposal).

I think you want the `Exit` statement instead. The `Exit` statement does not actually exit the program entirely, it's the equivalent of `return` and `break` in other languages:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/t234253x%28v%3dvs.84%29

> The Exit statement syntax has these forms:
>
> ```
>    Exit Do  
>    Exit For  
>    Exit Function  
>    Exit Property  
>    Exit Sub
> ```

Unfortunately you cannot use `Exit` inside the "top-level" script program code (i.e. outside of an explicit `Sub` or `Function`). My recommendation would be to wrap your program inside a `Sub` and your top-level program would simply be a call into the `Sub` and nothing else.

Also, do not confuse it with the `Stop` statement - which actually **pauses** script execution (like a breakpoint) until the user resumes it, so it isn't a real "stop execution" command. It also doesn't close handles:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/zw86czy2%28v%3dvs.84%29

> `Stop`: Suspends execution.
>   Using the `Stop` statement is similar to setting a breakpoint in the code.
>   The `Stop` statement suspends execution, but it does not close any files or clear any variables.

In your case, it's much simpler just to invert the `If`, like so:

```
With xlApp.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Title = "Select the folder to scan through sub-folders"
    .ButtonName = "Select this folder!"
    .InitialFileName = "\\..somepath"
    .InitialView = msoFileDialogViewSmallIcons
    If .Show = i Then
        Set HostFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
    End If
End With
```

(I assume `HostFolder` must be assigned with a `Set` statement as it's an `Object` instead of a value, but if it works without `Set` then that's fine)

### TL;DR:

- There is no singular `End` statement to end program execution in VBScript. It only exists in VB6, VBA and VB.NET.
- The `Stop` statement actually pauses execution like a breakpoint, it doesn't end execution.
- The `Exit` statement only works inside a parent control structure, `Sub` or `Function`, so it doesn't work inside the top-level program.

Comment: Thanks for the information . Just to follow up what do you mean when you say end doesn’t perform program clean up ? Normally I use exit sub anyway.

Comment: @MikeMirabelli It mainly applies to VB.NET. If you have active objects in-scope that implement `IDisposable` then when you call `End` (to end the program) the compiler will **not** call the `Dispose` methods on those disposable objects, even if you have a `Try/Finally` block. That's why it's a bad idea to use the `End` statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
If .Show <> i Then WScript.Quit
```

Comment: This only works if the VBScript is being executed inside a WScript context (e.g. by `cscript.exe` or `wscript.exe`). It may not work in other VBScript contexts (e.g. Classic ASP or a different host application).